# how do I read this recursive c programming

Tags: c

I confused to describe how this program running. maybe someone want to help me explain this code.
this my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int box(int a, int b, int t){
    if(b==0)
    {
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return box(a, b-1, t*a);
    }
}
int main(){
    printf("%d", box(3,4,2));
    return 0;
}
```

this program output is 162. its doesn't print t x a if t x a should be 6 x 6 x 6, I confused why 162 in output.

Comment: `box(3,4,2)` That's a small enough test case that you can write it down on paper step by step.

Comment: 2*3*3*3*3 = 162

Comment: "its doesn't print t x a if t x a should be 6 x 6 x 6, I confused why 162 in output." Sorry, I can't understand this sentence at all.

Answer (score 1):

in first iteration,
a=3, b=4, t=2

so, t*a =6

in second iteration,
a=3, b=3, t=6

so, t*a =18

in third iteration,
a=3, b=2, t=18

so, t*a =54

in fourth iteration,
a=3, b=1, t=54

so, t*a =162

in fifth iteration,
a=3, b=0, t=162

as b==0, so, it'll return 162

Answer (score 1):

I will walk through the program with you.

you are calling `box()` with `a=3` `b=4` `t=2`. Now its asking if b is 0, which is wrong so it goes to `else{}` then you are calling `box()` with `a=3` `b=3` `t=2*3` or `t=6`. The third time you call it you are doing `a=3` `b=2` `t=2*3*3` or `t=18`. Then the fourth time `a=3` `b=1` `t=2*3*3*3` or `t=54`, b isnt 0 yet so it calls again and finally goes `a=3` `b=0` `t=2*3*3*3*3` or `t=162` and returns 162, so all it does is starts with t and multiplies a, b times, so `t*a^b` is basically what you are really doing, not `(t*a)^3`

Answer (score 0):

This recursive program will run - until **b=0**

Function input `box(3,4,2)`

And `box` function structure `int box(int a, int b, int t)` which takes three integer parameters, and return `int` Value.

recursively return function control to `int box(int a, int b-1, int t*a)` until **b=0**

**b=4** calls `int box (3, 3, 6)`

**b=3** calls `int box (3, 2, 18)`

**b=2** calls `int box (3, 1, 54)`

now notice b becomes 1 or `int box( )` recursive call makes `b=1`

**b=1** calls `int box (3, 0, 54*3)`

and which in turn, gets terminated